# Converting 0x0AF8 to binary

Tags: binary, cpu-architecture

Can someone explain how this number is converted to binary ? 
 
  Number : **0x0AF8**   

It will be helpful for beginners to learn from

Answer (score 1):

In hexadecimal format, there are 16 possible digits:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F
```

Each hexadecimal digit can be converted into 4 binary digits:

```
0 = 0000
1 = 0001
2 = 0010
3 = 0011
4 = 0100
5 = 0101
6 = 0110
7 = 0111
8 = 1000
9 = 1001
A = 1010
B = 1011
C = 1100
D = 1101
E = 1110
F = 1111
```

Having said all that, you can convert `0x0AF8` to binary format as follows:

```
0    A    F    8
0000 1010 1111 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Number is written in hex so if you want to convert it to binary you need to just set 4 bit for each character of hex number.

for example:

```
HEX: 0x0AF8 
BINARY: 0000 1010 1111 1000
```

Actually you just change the representation not the content of number ...

Comment: Thanks very much but maybe you have a mistake here
BINARY: 0000 1010 1111 "0"100 ? , the zero